# How to perform complex looping operation on matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, determinants

I have a sample matrix like

```
 5 4 3  
 2 6 8   
 1 9 7
```

and I want output like

```
max(5*6,5*8,5*9,5*7)  // i!=j condition  
max(4*2,4*8,4*1,4*7)  
max(3*2,3*6,3*1,3*9)
```

And so on...

This maximum values obtained after computation should be in matrix form. I need to generalize it, therefore I need a generic code.

Comment: You should be able to solve this with `for` loops yourself. Demonstrate some effort in your question.

Comment: This code is giving the maximum value obtained for first row, I want the same operation on all rows provided the condition of "i not equal to j" remains same on all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the job done but is a pretty unimaginative solution, in that it just loops through the rows and columns performing the requested calculation instead of doing anything vectorized.

```
sapply(1:ncol(m), function(j) sapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) max(m[i,j]*m[-i,-j])))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   45   32   27
# [2,]   18   42   72
# [3,]    8   72   42
```

Data:

```
(m <- matrix(c(5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 7), nrow=3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    4    3
# [2,]    2    6    8
# [3,]    1    9    7
```

Comment: For nonnegative numbers, it should be faster to factor out the multiplication: `m[i,j]*max(m[-i,-j])` No idea if that's the scope of the OP's application, though.

Comment: @Frank I just moved the `max` outside the multiplication to address SvenHohenstein's comment that my previous solution (which is exactly what you're describing) only worked for non-negative matrices. We can't have it both ways, I'm afraid. Then again, I would imagine the efficiency hit you're describing is quite small.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't notice your first iteration of the answer. Yeah, as the size scales up, the `max` should dominate the cost, I guess.

Comment: Another version with `outer` `outer(1:nrow(m1), 1:ncol(m1), FUN= Vectorize(function(i,j) max(m1[i,j]*m1[-i,-j])))`